# Find unique contacts from mysql table

Tags: mysql

I have inherited a database that is bit tricky to clean up. I need to link the contacts correctly to the students. The database schema is like below :

**Tables**

```
Student : [Id, Name, ParentEmail]

Contact:[Id, Name, StudentId]
```

The data in the contact table is wrong with some  contacts attached to wrong student. Same contact can be assigned to two separate student so long as the [ParentEmail] is the same.

I need  to find all the contacts in the [contact] table that are assigned to wrong students(i.e. one or more student with different ParentEmail) as they are not from the same family.

Sample data

```
Student

    Id Name parentEmail
    ===================
    1  Jim   jim@parent.com
    2. Bob   jim@parent.com
    3. Rob   rob@parent.com

Contact:
   Id  Name       StudentId
   =========================
   1  Jim's Dad     1
   2  Jim's Dad     2  
   3. Jim's Dad     3
   4. Rob's Mum     3
```

This is the query I have come up with my limited mysql knowledge:

```
select name as ContactName from contact group by name having count(studentID) > 1;
```

How can I link it back to student table and work out that the ParentEmail is incorrect and the Record 3 in the contact's table is incorrect as the Contact Name and the ParentEmail are not the same.

Comment: There is a design problem here.  You should have a _junction_ table which relates students to contacts.  Absent this, I'm afraid to give an answer here.

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that every student can have more than one contact available like dad's email and mom's email. The strategy that I will depend on is to assume that part of the email before @ will contain the name of one of the children i.e. Jim and Bob are brothers. This part will be used to fetch the correct parent based on the naming of 'child's parent'.

```
SELECT * FROM 
Contact, Student
WHERE student.id = contact.studentID
AND contact.name 
NOT LIKE CONCAT('%',LEFT(student.parentEmail,LOCATE('@',student.parentEmail) - 1),'%')
```

Comment: thank you, but the strategy applied will not work as most of the email addresses are not the name of the contact. I will try to do the logic in the code rather than in SQL.

Comment: In the problem statement you mentioned "Contact Name and the ParentEmail are not the same". If that cannot be applied, how can you identify which one is correct?

Comment: @Neo Perhaps your initial assumption is false - but I agree that the task is essentially insoluble